# Count days by ID - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

By having the following table, how can I count the days by ID?
without use of for or any loop because it's large size data.

```
ID  Date 
a   01/01/2020
a   05/01/2020
a   08/01/2020
a   10/01/2020
b   05/05/2020
b   08/05/2020
b   12/05/2020
c   08/08/2020
c   22/08/2020
```

to have this result

```
ID  Date        Days Evolved Since Inicial date
a   01/01/2020  1
a   05/01/2020  4
a   08/01/2020  7
a   10/01/2020  9
b   05/05/2020  1
b   08/05/2020  3
b   12/05/2020  7
c   08/08/2020  1
c   22/08/2020  14
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534152/how-to-calculate-days-difference-between-successive-pandas-dataframe-rows-with

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Your best bet is to have whatever database you're pulling from do the heavy lifting for you in this case.

Comment: Why is "Days evolved since inicial date" == 1 and not 0 for the first date?

Comment: I doubt this can be done without a loop. Either you implement the loop or someone else already did it in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first values to new column, so possible subtract. Then if not duplicated datetimes is possible replace `0`:

```
df['new']=df['Date'].sub(df.groupby("ID")['Date'].transform('first')).dt.days.replace(0, 1)

print (df)
  ID       Date  new
0  a 2020-01-01    1
1  a 2020-01-05    4
2  a 2020-01-08    7
3  a 2020-01-10    9
4  b 2020-05-05    1
5  b 2020-05-08    3
6  b 2020-05-12    7
7  c 2020-08-08    1
8  c 2020-08-22   14
```

Or set `1` for first value of group by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['new'] = (df['Date'].sub(df.groupby("ID")['Date'].transform('first'))
                       .dt.days.where(df['ID'].duplicated(), 1))

print (df)
  ID       Date  new
0  a 2020-01-01    1
1  a 2020-01-05    4
2  a 2020-01-08    7
3  a 2020-01-10    9
4  b 2020-05-05    1
5  b 2020-05-08    3
6  b 2020-05-12    7
7  c 2020-08-08    1
8  c 2020-08-22   14
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you do it this way to avoid the `.apply` performance bottleneck?

Comment: @Timus exactly.

Comment: Thanks, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like (`df` your dataframe):

```
def days_evolved(sdf):
    sdf["Days_evolved"] = sdf.Date - sdf.Date.iat[0]
    sdf["Days_evolved"].iat[0] = pd.Timedelta(days=1)
    return sdf

df = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False, sort=False).apply(days_evolved)
```

Result for the sample:

```
  ID       Date Days_evolved
0  a 2020-01-01       1 days
1  a 2020-01-05       4 days
2  a 2020-01-08       7 days
3  a 2020-01-10       9 days
4  b 2020-05-05       1 days
5  b 2020-05-08       3 days
6  b 2020-05-12       7 days
7  c 2020-08-08       1 days
8  c 2020-08-22      14 days
```

If you want `int` instead of `pd.Timedelta` then do

```
df["Days_evolved"] = df["Days_evolved"].dt.days
```

at the end.